# How to save temp. changes of an object?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I need some advice how to handle the following case. I'm saving an object graph within core data. For simplicity lets say i have a User object (name, age, adress). Adress is another object with some properties. Now the User can change his Adress. If he changes it i need to remember these changes for the next order. After that i need to revert back to the original Adress. The User can also revert back at any time. Where should i save these temporary changes? I thought about adding a new entity like ChangedData but this somehow does not feel right. Basicly i need to remember the original object and if the User changes it i need to remember those for some Time as well. I hope i could express my problem well enough.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use an NSUndoManager paired with your managed object context. Just add the following code to

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
```

in your app delegate implementation:

```
NSUndoManager *undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
[managedObjectContext setUndoManager:undoManager];
```

then use [the methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of the undo manager to undo and redo your saves of the context.

Comment: This looks promising. Didnt know about it. I will try it.